Had this attempt to salvage naïve comprehension been studied before?
Is the following a possible way to overcome inconsistency with naive comprehension:
We add an $\in_n$ symbol for each natural $n$ to the signature of this theory, which is a first order theory with equality and all its axioms.
Then axiomatize:
Comprehension: $\exists x \forall y \, (y \in_n x \leftrightarrow \phi^n(y))$
where $\phi^n(y)$ has $\in_{n-1}$ as the maximal appearing membership symbol.
Extensionality: $  a \in_n x \land \forall z \, (z \in_n x \leftrightarrow z \in_m y) \to x=y$
Membership: $a \in_m x \land b \in_n x \to b \in_m x $

had this been done before? References?


Is this much different from TST?

I'm not an expert, but this looks quite similar to the stratification done in NF

@CalliopeRyan-Smith. Yes. It is much different from TST. TST is a multi-sorted theory, this is mono-sorted. TST doesn't have a universal set, but this theory has. TST has one membership symbol, while here we have infinitely many ones.

@AlessandroCodenotti, NO. NF is a quite different theory, there is no restriction here to stratified formulas, though this theory shares the feature of being mono-sorted, yet NF is formulated exactly in the language of ZF. The two theories does have a universal set, complements, etc.. Anyhow, this theory is completely different as far as syntax is concerned.

Do we have $m\leq n$ or vice-verse for the indices in the last two axioms, or are they just universally quantified for all $m,n$?

@AlecRhea, $n;m$ are metatheoretic, so we cannot quantify over them. The last two axioms are schemata having an axiom for each $n,m$, and there is no restriction to $m \leq n$.

I presume @AlecRhea meant “metatheoretically universally quantified”, which is exactly what a schema is.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, Yes. I understand but I thought I must make this comment to clarify matters. So, in this metatheoretic context, then the answer is yes to $n,m$ being just universally quantified.

What is your base theory that you're adding these axioms to? Is 'naïve comprehension' a theory? Does this theory have non-indexed membership already with some axioms, and you're adding indexed membership with these additional axioms? Or are these the only membership relations?

@AlecRhea I read this as a stand-alone axiom scheme.

@MonroeEskew I'm perhaps overly focused on the phrase "We add... to the signature of this theory, which is a first order theory with equality and all its axioms". So the base theory is just first order logic with equality, and we add these symbols/axioms?

@AlecRhea Yes, I think so.

@MonroeEskew Thank you.

@AlecRhea, sorry for being late. Yes, it is as such, the base theory is first order logic with equality including the axioms of equality, and then you add the $\in_n$ membership symbols, and the axioms about them. There is no general $\in$ membership symbol.

Can you construct (a version of) the natural numbers in this theory?

How do we avoid collapse due to the membership axiom? That is, for fixed $n',m',a',b'$ we have that $a'\in_{m'}x\wedge b'\in_{n'}x\implies b'\in_{m'}x$, so $b'\in_i x$ for $i=n',m'$. But then we can apply the axiom again to say that $b'\in_{n'}x\wedge a'\in_{m'}x\implies a'\in_{n'}x$, so $\in_{n'}$ and $\in_{m'}$ coincide on $x$, and since $x$ was an arbitrary object of the theory we have $\in_{n'}=\in_{m'}$, and since both indices were arbitrary we have that $\in_n=\in_m$ for all $n,m$. Where does this argument fail?

@AlecRhea What if there is no $a'$ with $a' \in_{m'} x$? Then even if $b' \in_{n'} x$, you can't usefully apply the membership axiom.

@pastebee Ah, so we can have sets 'uninhabited' by some membership relations, and these will cause the relations to be distinct in general, nice. But for any set that is inhabited by any two distinct membership relations, they coincide on that set?

Could you clarify in comprehension whether you insist that $\in_{n-1}$ occurs in $\phi^n$, or rather do you just mean that all $\in_m$ occuring in $\phi^n$ have $m<n$. For example, otherwise you are not treating the $=$ only formulas.

@JoelDavidHamkins, It's the latter, I mean the $m<n$ option.  The $=$ only formulas obey's that restriction, so the are all applicable.

I think that is the right way to do it, and that is how my answer takes it. This means that the superscript on $\phi^n$, however, could also be anything larger than that.

@JoelDavidHamkins, do you mean that there is no natural upper bound on $n$? If so, then yes of course.

@MonroeEskew, yes let $n=2$ and left $\phi^n(y)$ be the formula $y$ is von Neumann natural defined using the $\in_1, =$ primitives. So, we can define $\sf N$. Notice, that this theory can define a von Neumann natural for each concrete natural since we have $\forall z_1,\cdots \forall z_k \exists x \forall y , (y \in_1 x \leftrightarrow y=z_1 \lor \cdots \lor y=z_k)$. So, all of these would $\in_2$ members of $\sf N$. Similarly, we can define all the known arithmetical operators on $\sf N$.

@ZuhairAl-Johar I just meant that $n$ is not determined by $\phi$, since any larger $n$ also works, so the notation $\phi^n$ isn't very good.

@JoelDavidHamkins, Yes! What better notation you suggest?

I would write just $\phi$, but say it is part of the rank $n$ language if it has $\in_m$ only for $m<n$. That is, you are defining a hierarchy of languages, rather than putting labels on formulas.

Here is a model of your theory. Start with a countably infinite set of objects $X=\bigsqcup_n X_n$, partitioned into infinitely many infinite sections. We inductively define $\in_n$. Consider the various formulas $\phi^n(y,z)$ that use only at most $\in_m$ for $m<n$, with parameters $z$. With the various possible parameters $z$, these define certain subsets of $X$, but only countably many. For each such definable subset, which has not already arisen earlier, assign an object $x$ from $X_n$ to represent it, and define $y\in_n x\iff\phi^n(y,z)$ for this instance. That is, I pick the object to represent the set for each definable set, not for each formula. If the definable set had already occurred at an earlier stage $m<n$, then I use the same object $x\in X_m$ as previously, and define $y\in_n x$ for the same members $y$. Thus, we will satisfy comprehension.
One effect of using the earlier object when the set was already defined earlier is that whenever $y\in_m x$ then $y\in_n x$ for all $n\geq m$, since the same formula recurs at the higher level the way I described it, or if you insist that the higher membership symbols appear in the formula we can add a vacuous use of $\in_{n-1}$ to any formula, such as $(y\in_{n-1} x\vee y\notin_{n-1} x)$, and thereby pump up the syntactic level of the formula to any desired level $n$. So the level of membership doesn't matter—once you are in the set, you will be in at all higher levels as well, and all members of a given set start membership at the same level. This will give us the membership axiom.
And since I was careful always to reuse the old object whenever the definable set is the same, we will get extensionality.
Note that we do indeed get new definable sets at each stage. For example, if we take $\phi(y)$ as $y\notin_{n} y$, then this cannot be already represented at level $n$ by any object, and so it will define a new class at level $n+1$. And then we will have all the finite modifications of it, definable with parameters, making infinitely many new definable sets at that next level. So every object will  get used as a set at its level.
This method of argument is rather similar to some of the solutions of Frege's Basic Law V for first-order definability, as discussed in my paper

Fregean abstraction in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory: a deflationary account, Annals of Mathematics and Philosophy, 2023. (arxiv:2209.07845)

See the prior art section there, where I discuss this method, used in various work by Parsons, Bell, and Burgess. In particular:

Terence Parsons. “On the consistency of the first-order
portion of Frege’s logical system”. Notre Dame J. Formal
Logic 28.1 (1987), pp. 161–168. ISSN: 0029-4527. DOI:10.
1305/ndjfl/1093636853.

One can perform the construction over any given model already. That is, we can assume $X$ already has some other first-order structure, but then chop it into the sections and undertake this construction on top of it, allowing formulas $\phi^n$ in the full language. This is essentially how the Parsons method works.

Do you think this theory can interpret each $n$-order arithmetic? So, it might be at the strength of Mac Lane set theory? Which is the same of $\sf TST + Infinity$.

No, it is not strong enough (but I don't know anything about TST). If you start with $X$ as the standard model of arithmetic and do my construction on top, then this is rather low in the hyperarithmetic hierarchy, since you are just iterating a truth predicate $\omega$ many times. There is a model computable from $0^{(\omega^2)}$.

If we just want a finite fragment of the theory instead of the whole thing, then we don't even need a truth predicate, and so this argument works in PA. So the theory is at most the strength of first-order arithmetic. I'm not convinced it even interprets PA though - we can make things that look sort of like $\mathbb{N}$, but then I don't know how to make induction work.

@pastebee I was imagining starting with a model of arithmetic, and then defining the $\in_n$ relations as an expansion of this. I don't quite see how to define the $\in_n$ relations in PA, since we'd need to decide which formulas are equivalent, which is why I think a truth predicate is involved. Can you explain your idea a bit more?

If we just start with a naked set, however, then truth would be trivial, and so we could do the whole construction in PA I think. Perhaps that is what you meant.

I don't see why it makes a difference whether we start with a model of arithmetic or just a set? Or do you mean that the formulas can also include $+$ and $\cdot$?

But anyway, the key piece is that I said a finite fragment - if we fix finitely many formulas (in the metatheory), and finitely many levels of $\in$, then we don't need the entirety of a truth predicate, we can just handle each formula individually (or if you prefer, we can make it all work with just truth predicates for $\Sigma^0_n$ sentences for various $n$). This doesn't quite prove in PA that the entire theory is consistent, but it shows that if PA is consistent then the theory is consistent.

Yes, the Parsons construction take place over any first-order model, and the formulas allow the base language. If you just start with a naked set, then I agree it is very weak, but I still don't understand your proposal exactly.

If, for example, we take the theory that only contains $\in_0$, $\in_1$, $\in_2$, and which only allows Comprehension with five formulas $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$, $\varphi_3$, $\varphi_4$, then PA interprets this theory - since we only have to deal with five formulas, we don't run into the issue that PA can't define arithmetic truth, because we only need a "truth predicate" that works on these formulas in particular.

OK, I see. I believe you can get even the full theory, if you start only with a naked set, since equivalence of formulas will be relatively weak. For example, on an infinite set with no structure (or with infinitely many distinct constants) we can decide equivalence of formulas, and thereby define suitable $\in_0$ relations, and then iterate this idea I think in PA.

It might be possible but I think we have to be careful about it. The sets defined by formulas that don't contain $\in$ are exactly the finite and cofinite sets, which means that by $\in_1$ we can easily interpret arithmetic truth, defining the natural numbers as von Neumann ordinals, and $+$ and $\cdot$ by finding finite sets that code sufficient pieces of them. If we want to keep the strength down, we have to avoid giving the structure the real notion of finiteness.

OK, so the thing to do is to prove upper and lower bounds on the interpretative strength of the theory, not to throw it all out by going to finite fragments.
